# Pass Control By Name To findViewById

Tags: android

If you got:

Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.widget28);

where "widget28" is the name of your button, how can you pass this
into the findViewById as a String? or get it from R class as a string?

I want to get the Button instance by string and not by the hard code R.id.widget28 reference.

thanks

Comment: why do you need to use a string? This is not the way it is meant to be...

Comment: I want to get the Button instance by string and not by the hard code R.id.widget28 reference.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `findViewById` expects an int, not a string, so not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

But the general way to get a string from its resource id is `getString(R.string.theId)`. See the [Context API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) docs.

I don't believe even with reflection that you can get the variable's name, widget28, if you actually need it for some reason. You could look into using the button's `android:tag` element to store it in the XML file, you'd then retrieve it in code by using `yourButton.getTag()`, but I'd look into designing it differently.